# Synchronize Threads - C

Tags: c, multithreading

I have a C++ wrapper class that uses C code. `reading_function` is running in a thread, and the function only returns when `write_is_finished`. This function should read data when a new segment is wrote. `writing_function` is called when a new segment is available. So, my objective is to do write-read-write-etc. To make that possible I use an infinite loop, with `if else` statements   (**pseudo-code**):

```
int reading_function([parameters]){
//....
for(;;){
   sleep(_few_ms);
   if(is_writing == false){
      is_reading == true;
      //..read
      is_reading == false;
   }
   if(write_is_finished == true){
      return check_state;
   }
  }
}

int writing_function([parameters]){
//...
for(;;){
   sleep(_few_ms-2);
     if(is_reading == false){
       is_writing = true;
       //...write
       is_writing = false;
     }
    return check_state;
  }
}
```

The program is running good. But I want a more elegant solution. Since this is C code, called from a C++ class. I don't know how can I synchronize the read and write threads.

Comment: Modern C++ (C++ 11) has added features for parallel processing, the Thread Support Library which includes synchronization facilities like mutexes. You would be more portable if you used C++'s synchronization features and left only the foot work of actually moving the data to C (if you have a choice there). The naive looking attempt at synchronization in your example (`if(is_reading == false){ is_writing = true;`) is not going to work reliably.

Answer (score 1):

It may depend on the environment that the code will run. If it is going to run on Windows, you may use thread synchronization objects like Semaphore or Mutex, and WIn32API provides such function to create, control and release, e.g. CreateSemaphore, CreateMutex.

If it is going to run on Unix environment, you may use posix-supported synchronization objects, e.g. pthread_mutex_, or pthread_semaphore.. The usage of these are pretty much well documented so that you may write your code without meeting race conditions.